# Simple word processor and presentation application for elderly layman

Tags: office

I am searching for a very minimalistic or simple office application for an elderly layman. The criteria are as follows:

- Includes a **word processor** and a **presentation software** (could be separate applications)
- Should have only the **basic features**

  - For the word processor: titles, ordered and unordered lists, paragraphs, and similar
  - For the presentation software: titles, bullet points, and similar
- Suitable for an **elderly layman** who has no problems using LXDE desktop on his laptop and Android on his phone, but for whom Microsoft Office and LibreOffice are too complicated
- Runs on **Linux or Android**

Ideally, the process should be, where he types the content (e.g. a title or an unordered list) and marks it as such, either with a written tag or with the mouse. And the application formats everything automatically.

Do such applications exist?

Comment: Ageist! Why not replace "elderly" with "someone who doesn't get along with computers"? (only semi-joking ;-)